# Batch file "do move" not relocating files to specified directory

Tags: batch-file

I created a batch file to scan a directory including sub-directories for Solidworks file extensions (.slddrw, .sldprt, .sldasm) and move them to an archive directory.  The problem that I am having is that the move is not moving to my **Archive** directory but is instead moving the files to the parent directory of **Archive** namely **Archive_Test**

Here is the code that I am using:

```
::cd G:\OPS\OpsEng\Document
cd c:\Archive_Test

::Make the Archive directory in case it does not already exist
MD Archive

::SET @From="G:\OPS\OpsEng\Document"
SET @From="C:\Archive_Test\Document"

::SET @To="G:\OPS\OpsEng\Archive"
SET @To="C:\Archive_Test\Archive\"

pause

::Move files with Solidworks extensions
for /R %From% %%f in (*.slddrw, *.sldasm, *.sldprt) do move "%%f" "%To%"

pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working cause you set the variables in a wrong way/don't call them in their name later(you set '@To' and use 'To').

For example:

```
C:\Users\equinox93>SET @From="C:\Archive_Test\Document"

C:\Users\equinox93>echo %@From%
"C:\Archive_Test\Document"

C:\Users\equinox93>echo %From%
%From%
```

So to fix it just remove the '@' when setting them:

```
::cd G:\OPS\OpsEng\Document
cd c:\Archive_Test

::Make the Archive directory in case it does not already exist
MD Archive

::SET From="G:\OPS\OpsEng\Document"
SET From="C:\Archive_Test\Document"

::SET To="G:\OPS\OpsEng\Archive"
SET To="C:\Archive_Test\Archive\"

pause

::Move files with Solidworks extensions
for /R %From% %%f in (*.slddrw, *.sldasm, *.sldprt) do move "%%f" "%To%"

pause
```

This should work.
You can read more about 'set' command here:
http://ss64.com/nt/set.html

Comment: Changing `move "%%f" "%To%"` to `echo move "%%f" "%To%"` for debugging purposes, you will see something like `move "C:\Archive_Test\Document\a.slddrw" ""C:\Archive_Test\Archive\""` with target directory in **doubled** double quotes. Hence, read your link again and use `SET "To=C:\Archive_Test\Archive\"` instead of `SET To="C:\Archive_Test\Archive\"` (and, of course,  `set "From=etc."` as well).